# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Grid Design - Shifting columns/rows around

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

See this example https://jsfiddle.net/egx3c847/

I'm trying to have the "Files" and "Something Else" fall below the "Call Details" without touching the "Account Details", like this;

```
|--------------|-----------------|
|CALL DETAILS  | ACCOUNT DETAILS |
|1             |1                |
|2             |2                |
|--------------|3                |
|FILES         |-----------------|
|1             |
|--------------|
|SOMETHING ELSE|
|--------------|
```

But I'd also like them all to collapse below each other in a 'row-xs-12' style for each of them, but in a specific order of; CALL DETAILS, ACCOUNT DETAILS, FILES, SOMETHING ELSE... like this;

```
|---------------|
|CALL DETAILS   |
|1              |
|2              |
|---------------|
|ACCOUNT DETAILS|
|1              |
|2              |
|3              |
|---------------|
|FILES          |
|1              |
|---------------|
|SOMETHING ELSE |
|---------------|
```

Can anyone help me get the columns and rows right?

Comment: your fiddle does exactly what you want to do according to the images you have here

Comment: I think @Ridai want "FILES" col to slide up under "CALL DETAILS". That's not happening in the fiddle.

Comment: @Skelly this is what I see in OP fiddle using FF http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/987/7515791467.png so yes OP fiddle is already sliding Files under account details

Comment: @dippas Apologies, I should've mentioned the browser size should've been max for what I was trying to acheive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a media query to `float:right` the "ACCOUNT DETAILS" on larger screens only..

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .pull-right-md {
    float:right;
  }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/y0mvkmZF98

**Note:** The upcoming Bootstrap 4 will include [responsive floats](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#responsive-floats) (ie:`pull-md-right`) for this type of behavior so that you wouldn't need the custom CSS class: http://codeply.com/go/OcF6HGnHOj

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="call-details">Call details</div>
      <div class="files">Files</div>
      <div class="something-else">Something else</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="account-details">Account details</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var accountDetails = $('.account-details'),
    accountDetailsParent = accountDetails.parent(),
    callDetails = $('.call-details');

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 768) {
    callDetails.after(accountDetails);
  } else {
    accountDetailsParent.append(accountDetails)
  }
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vpx55ey6/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, to be very concrete (you might want to add some off-set if you wish to center a little bit your content) :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <p>Call details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <p>Account details</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Files</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Something else</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```